# Error on Batch Apex for sun.security.validator

Tags: apex, batch, callout

I`m making calls to the outbound REST API from Salesforce via Batch apex. Most of the calls are working fine, except in some cases, Im getting below error. For example, if I run 200 batches (with batch size as 1), Im getting atleast 10 batches fail per execution but remaining 190 work fine.

> First error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Are all of the callouts going to the same endpoint?

Comment: @DavidReed - Yes, they are! We are just increment the endpoint by 1 since our partners API support pagination. For example, https://endpoint.com/1 (to get records on page 1)

Comment: Does this relate here anyway, worth taking a look -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ & http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html

Comment: Related: [Why do I get 'PKIX path building failed' exception with my callout?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/5603/102)

Answer (score 11):

This happens when your endpoint uses a **Load Balancer**.

So when you make calls in quick succession the Load Balancer Splits them to  different servers. This is the reason why it doesn't happen every time and in few occurrences.

[image].

So in One of the end server, the certificate assigned is not valid or properly configured.

Once your 3rd party guy configures Valid certificate you will stop seeing this issue.

Salesforce only supports a certain set of certificates, you can view them here.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates

Image Source: Google.